# Remove "Password reset instructions" hint on reset you password page?

Tags: views, 8, theming

Could not find any hooks or templates for it.

[image: Hint]

Comment: I think this link useful for you please check https://gist.github.com/zviryatko/37c01dcd2e24ae1674f7
Otherwise, you can try this module 
https://www.drupal.org/project/noreqnewpass

Comment: Did my answer help you? Is so please accept it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `hook form alter` like this:

```
function mymodule_form_alter($form_id, &$form) {

  if ($form_id == 'user_edit') {
    $form['fieldname'] = '';
  }
}
```

If you install devel and kint, then you kan `kint($form)`, to see what the fieldname is.